# Building a search results page via php

Tags: php, mysql, search, post

I need to build HTML page to show and organize my results.  Where do I place the HTML?  I tried it and I get errors.  Does it go inside the php script?  after the php script? before?  Confused.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
if (!empty($_POST['reg'])) {

    $record = $_POST['reg'];

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM reg_add WHERE reg='" . mysql_real_escape_string($record) . "'");
    $result = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($result != 0) {

        $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);

        $connect_date = $row['connect_date'];
        $reg = $row['reg'];
        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $last_name = $row['last_name'];
        $nickname = $row['nickname'];
        $gender = $row['gender'];
        $birthday = $row['birthday'];
        $home_state = $row['home_state'];
        $national = $row['national'];
        $location = $row['location'];


    } else {
        header("Location: search_error1.php");
        exit;
    }

} else {
    header("Location: search_error2.php");
    exit;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: `I tried it and I get errors` What did you try and what errors did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is embeddable into HTML, so you can write your html markup right in php file. You just need to place all your php code inside `<?php ?>`:

```
<?php
    //php code
?>
<html>
<!-- ... -->
</html>
<?php /* php again */ ?>
```

PHP interpreter simply ignores all text written outside the php tag (`<?php ?>`) and writes it directly to stdout.

So for you it will be something like this:

```
<?php

// ...

if ($result != 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $connect_date = $row['connect_date'];
        $reg = $row['reg'];
        $first_name = $row['first_name'];
        $last_name = $row['last_name'];
        $nickname = $row['nickname'];
        $gender = $row['gender'];
        $birthday = $row['birthday'];
        $home_state = $row['home_state'];
        $national = $row['national'];
        $location = $row['location'];
?>
  First name: <?php echo $first_name ?><br/>
  Last name: <?php echo $last_name ?><br/>
  ...
<?php
    }
}

// ...

?>
```

Comment: I tried what you wrote and my error pages did not work from the script.

Comment: It appears the following do not work:  } else {
            header("Location: search_error1.php");
            exit;
        }

    } else {
        header("Location: search_error2.php");
        exit;

Comment: Again, the error pages are not working if I type in the wrong number or no number.

Comment: What do you mean by "error pages are not working"? No redirect to search_error1.php occur or what?